# How can I store the output of an awk command as a bash script variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

When operating in the linux terminal I can enter the following: command

'''
awk 'FNR==1 {print$5}' SNextractedstats.txt
'''

To display the value in the first row and fifth column of a text file.

I would like to be able to save this value as a variable in a bash script to be able to do sums and call using Echo, how would I go about doing this?
Thank you

Comment: http://tldp,org -> Bash guides

Answer (score 1):

Read `man bash` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html an do something like

```
myvar="$(awk 'FNR==1 {print$5}' SNextractedstats.txt)"
```